# Authentication in custom app and wordpress at the same time?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, user-input

I have an app on domain.tld and I use WordPress for the blog of the app on domain.tld/blog. The app has users and I would like to have the users logged in to WordPress when they login to the app, so that when they comment blog posts they would be already logged in and be using the username from the app. Also this would help me build a dynamic menu that would display login and signup menu items when user is not logged in and dashboard and logout menu items when the user is logged in. The login would have to be one and only and that would be the login form from the app. Users won't need to administer anything on the WordPress end, so I would also disable the WordPress panel for non-admin users. What is the best method to approach this? I take it only the WordPress login cookie has to be set by the app on app login and this would log the user in both the app and WordPress having in mind when registering on the app, it creates the same user in the db of WordPress. I tried this on my app:

```
if ( $login_valid ) {
    require_once '<path_to_wordpress>/wp-load.php';
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id_var ); // set logged in cookie for that user id, which just logged in my app, so they would be logged in on blog, too.

}
```

Now what that did was to redirect after the login to the blog rather than the app dashboard. Any suggestions, please? To simplify the question: how to achieve login of WordPress users from another app with the credentials from the app?

Answer (score 0):

The users on your APP should have a corresponding wp_user record on your blog. You can do it like this:

1. When user register on your APP , call an ajax request to create wp_user account to your Blog.
2. Save the user_id from the APP to the Blog's wp_user custom post meta.
3. When the user log in to your APP, call an ajax request to the Blog that will log in their wp_user account programatically (the key will be user_id from the APP).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The users already have the same ID on both databases. I am missing part 3. :) Cookie won't be enough? I think your suggestion is also less secure.